# Jquery Plugin will not work with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks for the help in advance. I am relatively new to jquery and plugins as a whole. i did some research and have been struggling with this plugin for at least 3 weeks now.

The problem is i am trying to have multiple elements work with one plugin.
The plugin code is as follows

```
    ;(function($){
$.fn.zoom = function(options){
    //
    var _option = {
        align: "left",              // 
        thumb_image_width: 300,     // 
        thumb_image_height: 400,    // 
        source_image_width: 900,    // 
        source_image_height: 1200,  // 
        zoom_area_width: 600,       // 
        zoom_area_height: "justify",// 
        zoom_area_distance: 10,     // 
        zoom_easing: true,          //
        click_to_zoom: false,
        zoom_element: "auto",
        show_descriptions: true,
        description_location: "bottom",
        description_opacity: 0.7,
        small_thumbs: 3,            //
        smallthumb_inactive_opacity: 0.4,   // 
        smallthumb_hide_single: true,       // 
        smallthumb_select_on_hover: false,
        smallthumbs_position: "bottom",     //
        show_icon: true,
        hide_cursor: false,         // 
        speed: 600,                 // 
        autoplay: true,             // 
        autoplay_interval: 6000,    // 
        keyboard: true,
        right_to_left: false,
    }

    if(options){
        $.extend(_option, options);
    }

    var $ul = $(this);
    if($ul.is("ul") && $ul.children("li").length && $ul.find(".bzoom_big_image").length){

        $ul.addClass('bzoom clearfix').show();
        var $li = $ul.children("li").addClass("bzoom_thumb"),
            li_len = $li.length,
            autoplay = _option.autoplay;
        $li.first().addClass("bzoom_thumb_active").show();
        if(li_len<2){
            autoplay = false;
        }

        $ul.find(".bzoom_thumb_image").css({width:_option.thumb_image_width, height:_option.thumb_image_height}).show();

        var scalex = _option.thumb_image_width / _option.source_image_width,
            scaley = _option.thumb_image_height / _option.source_image_height,
            scxy = _option.thumb_image_width / _option.thumb_image_height;

        var $bzoom_magnifier, $bzoom_magnifier_img, $bzoom_zoom_area, $bzoom_zoom_img;

        // 遮罩显示的区域
        if(!$(".bzoom_magnifier").length){
            $bzoom_magnifier = $('<li class="bzoom_magnifier"><div class=""><img src="" /></div></li>');
            $bzoom_magnifier_img = $bzoom_magnifier.find('img');

            $ul.append($bzoom_magnifier);

            $bzoom_magnifier.css({top:top, left:left});
            $bzoom_magnifier_img.attr('src', $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active .bzoom_thumb_image').attr('src')).css({width: _option.thumb_image_width, height: _option.thumb_image_height});
            $bzoom_magnifier.find('div').css({width:_option.thumb_image_width*scalex, height:_option.thumb_image_height*scaley});
        }

        // 大图
        if(!$('.bzoom_zoom_area').length){
            $bzoom_zoom_area = $('<li class="bzoom_zoom_area"><div><img class="bzoom_zoom_img" /></div></li>');
            $bzoom_zoom_img = $bzoom_zoom_area.find('.bzoom_zoom_img');
            var top = 0,
                left = 0;

            $ul.append($bzoom_zoom_area);

            if(_option.align=="left"){
                top = 0;
                left = 0 + _option.thumb_image_width + _option.zoom_area_distance;
            }

            $bzoom_zoom_area.css({top:top, left:left});
            $bzoom_zoom_img.css({width: _option.source_image_width, height: _option.source_image_height});
        }

        var autoPlay = {
            autotime : null,
            isplay : autoplay,

            start : function(){
                if(this.isplay && !this.autotime){
                    this.autotime = setInterval(function(){
                        var index = $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').index();
                        changeLi((index+1)%_option.small_thumbs);
                    }, _option.autoplay_interval);
                }
            },

            stop : function(){
                clearInterval(this.autotime);
                this.autotime = null;
            },

            restart : function(){
                this.stop();
                this.start();
            }
        }

        // 循环小图
        var $small = '';
        if(!$(".bzoom_small_thumbs").length){
            var top = _option.thumb_image_height+10,
                width = _option.thumb_image_width,
                smwidth = (_option.thumb_image_width / _option.small_thumbs) - 10,
                smheight = smwidth / scxy,
                ulwidth = 
                smurl = '',
                html = '';

            for(var i=0; i<_option.small_thumbs; i++){
                smurl = $li.eq(i).find('.bzoom_thumb_image').attr("src");

                if(i==0){
                    html += '<li class="bzoom_smallthumb_active"><img src="'+smurl+'" alt="small" style="width:'+smwidth+'px; height:'+smheight+'px;" /></li>';
                }else{
                    html += '<li style="opacity:0.4;"><img src="'+smurl+'" alt="small" style="width:'+smwidth+'px; height:'+smheight+'px;" /></li>';
                }
            }

            $small = $('<li class="bzoom_small_thumbs" style="top:'+top+'px; width:'+width+'px;"><ul class="clearfix" style="width: 485px;">'+html+'</ul></li>');
            $ul.append($small);

            $small.delegate("li", "click", function(event){
                changeLi($(this).index());
                autoPlay.restart();
            });

            autoPlay.start();
        }

        function changeLi(index){
            $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').removeClass('bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, _option.speed, function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
            $small.find('.bzoom_smallthumb_active').removeClass('bzoom_smallthumb_active').stop().animate({opacity: _option.smallthumb_inactive_opacity}, _option.speed);

            $li.eq(index).addClass('bzoom_thumb_active').show().stop().css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1}, _option.speed);
            $small.find('li:eq('+index+')').addClass('bzoom_smallthumb_active').show().stop().css({opacity: _option.smallthumb_inactive_opacity}).animate({opacity: 1}, _option.speed);

            $bzoom_magnifier_img.attr("src", $li.eq(index).find('.bzoom_thumb_image').attr("src"));
        }




        _option.zoom_area_height = _option.zoom_area_width / scxy;
        $bzoom_zoom_area.find('div').css({width:_option.zoom_area_width, height:_option.zoom_area_height});

        $li.add($bzoom_magnifier).mousemove(function(event){
            var xpos = event.pageX - $ul.offset().left,
                ypos = event.pageY - $ul.offset().top,
                magwidth = _option.thumb_image_width*scalex,
                magheight = _option.thumb_image_height*scalex,
                magx = 0,
                magy = 0,
                bigposx = 0,
                bigposy = 0;

            if(xpos < _option.thumb_image_width/2){
                magx = xpos > magwidth/2 ? xpos-magwidth/2 : 0;
            }else{
                magx = xpos+magwidth/2 > _option.thumb_image_width ? _option.thumb_image_width-magwidth : xpos-magwidth/2;
            }
            if(ypos < _option.thumb_image_height/2){
                magy = ypos > magheight/2 ? ypos-magheight/2 : 0;
            }else{
                magy = ypos+magheight/2 > _option.thumb_image_height ? _option.thumb_image_height-magheight : ypos-magheight/2;
            }

            bigposx = magx / scalex;
            bigposy = magy / scaley;

            $bzoom_magnifier.css({'left':magx, 'top':magy});
            $bzoom_magnifier_img.css({'left':-magx, 'top': -magy});

            $bzoom_zoom_img.css({'left': -bigposx, 'top': -bigposy});
        }).mouseenter(function(event){
            autoPlay.stop();

            $bzoom_zoom_img.attr("src", $(this).find('.bzoom_big_image').attr('src'));
            $bzoom_zoom_area.css({"background-image":"none"}).stop().fadeIn(400);

            $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({'opacity':0.5}, _option.speed*0.7);
            $bzoom_magnifier.stop().animate({'opacity':1}, _option.speed*0.7).show();
        }).mouseleave(function(event){
            $bzoom_zoom_area.stop().fadeOut(400);
            $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({'opacity':1}, _option.speed*0.7);
            $bzoom_magnifier.stop().animate({'opacity':0}, _option.speed*0.7, function(){
                $(this).hide();
            });

            autoPlay.start();
        })
    }
}
    })(jQuery);
```

To use the Plugin i understand that i have to trigger it like this

```
$("#bzoom").zoom({
zoom_area_width: 400,
autoplay_interval :7000,
small_thumbs : 4,
autoplay : true});
```

But what i want to do is to use more than one element so that i can have two different elements showing images like this

```
$("#bzoom, #bzoom2").zoom({
zoom_area_width: 400,
autoplay_interval :7000,
small_thumbs : 4,
autoplay : true});
```

This does not work. It will only work with one element and not two. I am not sure what to do.

what happens is, every time i include a second element, the first one stops working as well. Its as if there is a conflict somewhere.

My html is something like this

```
    <div class="bzoom_wrap" style="margin-left:60px">
    <ul id="bzoom"> 
        <li>
            <img class="bzoom_thumb_image" src="../images/500_thumb1.jpg" title="first img" />
            <img class="bzoom_big_image" src="../images/1000_big1.jpg"/>
        </li>
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>


            <div class="bzoom_wrap" style="margin-left:60px">
    <ul id="bzoom2"> 
        <li>
            <img class="bzoom_thumb_image2" src="../images/500_thumb1.jpg" title="first img" />
            <img class="bzoom_big_image2" src="../images/1000_big1.jpg"/>
        </li>
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to achieve what you needed with either solution?

Comment: No, i keep getting half working code on both image zooms. For example, i will get a large image showing ok, but no thumb nails to switch them, and an opposite effect on the other

Comment: When you are finding elements underneath your ul they should be the same class in the markup. For example $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_image') will only work on the first element. Make you classes the same for both elements, you could always change the ids to a single class which you can then call $('.bzoom').zoom() rather than $('#bzoom, #bzoom2').zoom()

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `each` loop in your plugin:

```
$.fn.zoom = function(options){
    $(this).each(function(eachElement){
         //code here
    });
}
```

Comment: This will only work for one. I think the issue i am having is every time i try to add the class (".bzoom_big_image") and (".bzoom_big_image2") in the plugin. It seems to work partially in both of them

Answer (score 0):

Try `each` loop

**JS:**

```
$("[id^=bzoo]").each(function() {
        $(this).zoom({
            zoom_area_width: 400,
            autoplay_interval: 7000,
            small_thumbs: 4,
            autoplay: true
        });
});
```

More about attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors